# Graph network plot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I recently installed Mathematica 12.2. I'm now getting this output when I want to generate a directed graph that has 2817 nodes and 30,670 edges. I used to generate the graph of these nodes without a problem but now I'm getting the output below and not a picture of the network.

```
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

This is my output
[image]

Comment: Some experimentation suggests that a plot will not be generated automatically by `Graph` if you have 10,000 or more vertices or edges. You could use `GraphPlot@Graph[...]` to force plotting.

Comment: Play with larger values for the sub-options `"EdgeCountThreshold" ` and `"VertexCountThreshold"`  of the system option `"GraphOptions"` using `SetSystemOptions`?  (See the defaults using `SystemOptions["GraphOptions"]`)

Comment: SystemOptions["GraphOptions"]
Out[4]= {GraphOptions->{CacheResults->True,EdgeCountThreshold->10000,RenderingOrder->VertexFirst,VertexCountThreshold->1000}}

Comment: Looks like 10,000 edges and 1,000 vertexes are the threshold defaults. MacroB's forced plotting works well.

Answer (score 11):

Default values for the edge count and vertex count thresholds are 10000 and 1000, respectively:

```
SystemOptions["GraphOptions"]
```

> ```
>  {"GraphOptions" -> {"CacheResults" -> True, 
>   "EdgeCountThreshold" -> 10000, "RenderingOrder" -> "VertexFirst", 
>   "VertexCountThreshold" -> 1000}}
> ```

With default settings a graph with, say, 1100 vertices and 11000 edges is not rendered:

```
RandomGraph[{1100, 11000}]
```

[image]

Increasing these thresholds gives the desired result:

```
SetSystemOptions["GraphOptions" -> {"EdgeCountThreshold" -> 20000,     
    "VertexCountThreshold" -> 2000}];

RandomGraph[{1100, 11000}]
```

[image]

Comment: If getting a `Graphics` object  (as  opposed to a `Graph` object) as output is acceptable, you can also use the workaround suggested by MarcoB in comments  (wrap `Graph` with `GraphPlot`)  without having to change system option settings.

Comment: Many thanks to you both MarcoB and kglr for sharing your wisdom ... much appreciated and very helpful!! ... prg