# Drawing graphs with many vertices in mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have been using Mathematica to make graphs out of adjacency matrices. However, once the adjacency matrices get very large, Mathematica does not draw them. My adjacency matrix is a 360x360 matrix. Is there a way to get Mathematica to draw very large graphs? If not, is there an alternative to mathematica that I can use that has a similar high visual quality?

The method I have been using is adj={{},{},{},...,{}} is my adjacency matrix and then
g=AdjacencyGraph[adj] will give a picture of the graph. I would prefer an approach that allows for a vector image output, eg. *.svg.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Graph network plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238743/125). Try if [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238749/125) gives what you need.

Comment: THANKS!!! Perfect!