# Visualising very large poset with thousands of vertices and edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I wrote the following code for a large poset. It has over 5000 vertices and over 30000 edges.
I used the form "Graph[{a <-> b, a <-> c, etc }, VertexCoordinates -> {a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, etc ...]. It evaluates correctly but does not visualise. How can I make the threshold for the number of vertices, edges, etc larger so that it will be visualised in Mathematica?

g = Graph[ {{0}<->{0, 1}, {0}<->{0, 2}, {0}<->{0, 3}, {0}<->{0, 4}, {0}<->{0, 5}, {0}<->{0, 11}, {0}<->{0, 24}, {0}<->{0, 101}, {0}<->{0, 100}, {1}<->{0, 1}, {1}<->{1, 2}, {1}<->{1, 3}, {1}<->{1, 4}, {1}<->{1, 5}, {1}<->{6, 1}, {1}<->{1, 7}, {1}<->{8, 1}, {1}<->{1, 9}, {1}<->{10, 1}, {1}<->{1, 11}, ....},

VertexCoordinates -> {...,{29, 1, 3, 30, 5, 102}-> {344, 5}, {14, 1, 3, 30, 102, 5}-> {345, 5}, {14, 1, 3, 12, 5, 102}-> {346, 5}, {8, 1, 3, 12, 102, 5}-> {347, 5}, {8, 1, 3, 97, 5, 102}-> {348, 5}, {94, 1, 3, 97, 102, 5}-> {349, 5}, {94, 1, 3, 93, 100, 5}-> {350, 5}, {48, 1, 3, 93, 5, 100}-> {351, 5}, {48, 1, 3, 47, 100, 5}-> {352, 5}, {46, 1, 3, 47, 5, 100}-> {353, 5}, {46, 1, 3, 101, 100, 5}-> {354, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 101, 5, 100}-> {355, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 11, 100, 5}-> {356, 5}, {8, 1, 3, 11, 5, 100}-> {357, 5}, {8, 1, 3, 97, 100, 5}-> {358, 5}, {94, 1, 3, 97, 5, 100}-> {359, 5}, {78, 1, 103, 3, 104, 5}-> {360, 5}, {34, 1, 103, 3, 5, 104}-> {361, 5}, {34, 1, 35, 3, 104, 5}-> {362, 5}, {20, 1, 35, 3, 5, 104}-> {363, 5}, {20, 1, 87, 3, 104, 5}-> {364, 5}, {86, 1, 87, 3, 5, 104}-> {365, 5}, {86, 1, 85, 3, 104, 5}-> {366, 5}, {60, 1, 85, 3, 5, 104}-> {367, 5}, {60, 1, 79, 3, 104, 5}-> {368, 5}, {78, 1, 79, 3, 5, 104}-> {369, 5}, {88, 1, 3, 91, 5, 105}-> {370, 5}, {29, 1, 3, 91, 105, 5}-> {371, 5}, {29, 1, 3, 33, 5, 105}-> {372, 5}, {34, 1, 3, 33, 105, 5}-> {373, 5}, {34, 1, 3, 103, 5, 105}-> {374, 5}, {78, 1, 3, 103, 105, 5}-> {375, 5}}]

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you feed your `Graph[]` to `GraphPlot[]`?

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is very helpful. I will definitely need to stretch out the vertical positions a great deal to make it able to seen.

Comment: I think though that the size of the vertices also becomes a problem

Comment: Then, you should be exploring the options of `GraphPlot[]`, like `VertexSize`...

Comment: Thanks J. M., you've been extremely helpful :-)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Graph network plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238743/125)