# Max graph limit change mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a huge graph in Mathematica, and I want to display it. The only problem is that it stores itself as a "graph" object rather than displaying the edges and vertices. Is there any way to force Mathematica to display the graph?

Thank you!

Comment: does [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238749/125) help?

Comment: In short, use `GraphPlot` to request plotting explicitly.